# Using IBActions with UIButtons without IBOutlet

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uibutton, ibaction

Sorry for the unclear title. I want to be able to add IBAction methods to a button I added in the following way:

(.h class)

```
{
    UIButton *button;
}
-(IBAction)ButtonReleased:(id)sender
```

(.m class)

```
{
    -(IBAction)ButtonReleased:(id)sender
    {
        //Actions done by button pointer
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [PlayButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)];
        [PlayButton setTitle:@"PlayButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:PlayButton];
    }
}
```

The question is, how can I connect the UIButton button action (say, TouchUpInside) to the ButtonReleased method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonReleased:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```